# Cassandra or Hadoop Hive or MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, cassandra, hbase

I am Developing a Web Crawler,Which is Good for storing data? Cassandra or Hadoop Hive or MySQL?and why?i am having 1TB of Data from past 6 Months in my MySQL DB,i need to index them and i need to get the out put in my search ASAP,and as i think,it will store more amount of DATA,like 10 Peta Byes as my crawler are working fast,i need to get the read/write operation fast,i need to integrate it in my PHP app

Comment: All of them. Depends on your needs, which you did not describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on details of your requirements, but I think that in your case HBase would be the best option.
Using HBase as a web-crawler database is well documented and it's HBase's use that is described in BigTable whitepaper.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something that's meant for finding documents based on their content -- it should be based on an inverted index. I think that the most natural fit would be [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).

See also [this article](http://highscalability.com/how-rackspace-now-uses-mapreduce-and-hadoop-query-terabytes-data) about a  Hadoop-Lucene stack for querying terabytes of documents.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements , Use HBASE in case of real time fast analysis of streaming data.
Cassandra is best suited for fast write scenarios, as its read is slow compared to HBASE.

Hive is also a good alternative . For improved hive performance use Impala.